# Clang errors "expected register" with inline x86 assembly (works with GCC)

Tags: x86, clang, inline-assembly

I wrote a demo with some inline assembly (showing how to shift an array of memory right one bit) and it compiles and functions fine in GCC.  However, the with Clang, I'm not sure if it's generating bad code or what but it's unhappy that I'm using memory despite the "rm" constraint.

I've tried many compilers and versions via [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) and while it works on all x86/x86_64 versions of GCC, it fails with all versions of Clang.  I'm unsure if the problem is my code or if I found a compiler bug.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  unsigned char bytes[16] =
  {
    0xFF, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81,
    0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81,
    0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81,
    0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0xF0,
  };

  __asm__ volatile("shrl $1, 12(%0); \n"
                   "rcrl $1,  8(%0); \n"
                   "rcrl $1,  4(%0); \n"
                   "rcrl $1,  0(%0); \n"
                   : : "rm" (bytes));

  printf("bytes: %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x \n",
         bytes[15], bytes[14], bytes[13], bytes[12], bytes[11], bytes[10], bytes[9], bytes[8],
         bytes[7], bytes[6], bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

compilation output:

```
.<source>:13:20: error: expected register here
.  __asm__ volatile("shrl $1, 12(%0); \n"
.                   ^
.<inline asm>:1:14: note: instantiated into assembly here
.        shrl $1, 12(-88(%rbp)); 
.                    ^
.<source>:14:21: error: expected register here
.                   "rcrl $1,  8(%0); \n"
.                    ^
.<inline asm>:2:13: note: instantiated into assembly here
.rcrl $1,  8(-88(%rbp)); 
.            ^
.<source>:15:21: error: expected register here
.                   "rcrl $1,  4(%0); \n"
.                    ^
.<inline asm>:3:13: note: instantiated into assembly here
.rcrl $1,  4(-88(%rbp)); 
.            ^
.<source>:16:21: error: expected register here
.                   "rcrl $1,  0(%0); \n"
.                    ^
.<inline asm>:4:13: note: instantiated into assembly here
.rcrl $1,  0(-88(%rbp)); 
.            ^
```

Comment: Note that on recent CPUs with efficient `shrd`, it's more efficient to load into registers and use `shrd $1, src_of_high_bit, dst`.  That allows more instruction-level parallelism. Although Skylake can only run 1/clock `shrd`, but Sandybridge can run it on 2 ports.  So instead of a ripple dependency chain through FLAGS, each operation can just read from its next higher source operand in parallel.  It's not faster on Zen, though, where shrd by immediate is 6 uops, vs. 1 on Intel.  https://uops.info/table.html

Comment: Also, apparently you're compiling in 64-bit mode, so it would be more than twice as efficient to use 64-bit operand-size!  (Just SHR + RCR, saving 2x RCR, which are each more expensive than an SHR).  Probably not worth using SSE2, although that's possible with some shuffle / OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm unsure if the problem is my code or if I found a compiler bug.

The problem is your code. In GNU assembler, parentheses are used to dereference like unary `*` is in C, and you can only dereference a register, not memory. As such, writing `12(%0)` in the assembly when `%0` might be memory is wrong. It only happens to work in GCC because GCC chooses to use a register for `"rm"` there, while Clang chooses to use memory. You should use `"r" (bytes)` instead.

Also, you need to tell the compiler that your assembly is going to modify the array, either with a `memory` clobber or by adding `*(unsigned char (*)[16])bytes` as an output. Right now, it's allowed to optimize your `printf` to just hardcode what the values were at the beginning of the program.

Fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  unsigned char bytes[16] =
  {
    0xFF, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81,
    0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81,
    0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81,
    0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0xF0,
  };

  __asm__ volatile("shrl $1, 12(%1); \n"
                   "rcrl $1,  8(%1); \n"
                   "rcrl $1,  4(%1); \n"
                   "rcrl $1,  0(%1); \n"
                   : "+m" (*(unsigned char (*)[16])bytes) : "r" (bytes));

  printf("bytes: %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x \n",
         bytes[15], bytes[14], bytes[13], bytes[12], bytes[11], bytes[10], bytes[9], bytes[8],
         bytes[7], bytes[6], bytes[5], bytes[4], bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using just `"+m" (bytes)` (without the cast) should work, as `bytes` is already an array.

Comment: @ChrisDodd `*bytes` isn't though.

Comment: Correct, so `"+m"(bytes)` actually gives you the array object by value as a memory operand, unlike anything you can do in normal C where it would "decay" to a pointer.  @ChrisDodd is correct.  In fact, that's how the cast (dereffing a ptr-to-array) actually works to tell GCC about the whole array being a read/write operand.  Of course, it's probably a good idea to still use the cast so it doesn't break when you put it in a function that takes a `void *bytes` arg.

Comment: However, you don't need a separate pointer arg; you can let the compiler pick the addressing mode and offset it because AT&T syntax makes that work.  `12 + %0` works, so that can save the compiler an LEA and a register.  It will warn if it expands to `12 + (%rdi)` but does still work.